# Assinging arbitrary values to Object type

Tags: java, object

I have a question regarding the following code:

```
Object o;
o = "Some string";
System.out.println(o.toString());   //Some string
o = 666;
System.out.println(o.toString());   //666
```

How come that the content of the Object can be printed without any casts? Is it really so universal container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just due to polymorphism. Object defines the method toString(), and it is overridden in String and Integer.

```
Object o;
o = "Some string";                  // o is now a String.
System.out.println(o.toString());   // so calls String::toString().
o = 666;                            // o is now an Integer.
System.out.println(o.toString());   // so calls Integer::toString().
```

If the method toString() had not been defined in Object, the cast would have been necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The `toString()` method is defined on the Object class so, in a sense, yes it really is such a 'universal' container.

However, much of the useful functionality associated with any particular object is in the references of the object's subtype. Once you've assigned a String to an Object you can't access things like `substring()`. The functionality you can access with an Object reference is limited.

Answer (score 0):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html):
*Class Object is the root of the class hierarchy. Every class has Object as a superclass. All objects, including arrays, implement the methods of this class.*

Its not a *universal container* so to speak. Primitive types are not `Object`.

In your example, you are storing `String` and `Integer` which inherit from `Object`. Since `Object` has `toString()` method, you don't need to cast it.